# regex to check if IP address's 4th octet is greather than XXX

Tags: regex, groovy

in my program i have to check against a IP address and decesion has to be made only if ip address's 4th octet is greater than XXX number. XXX = 120 for example.

```
       for example: 
       IP1 = 10.100.1.121
       IP2 = 10.100.1.119
       IP3 = 10.100.1.122

if($IP =~ /10\.100\.1\.**<120**/)
```

i am tried something like `10\.100\.1\.[2-9][3-9][9-9]` but it is not correct.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: So, you basically want a regex that matches from 0 till 120? Or from 120 to infinity?

Comment: anything above 120 should be matched.

Comment: There's a [regex for range utility online](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range). With putting it together for >= 121 would result in this regex: `10\.100\.1\.(?:12[1-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`

Comment: Thanks and Could you explain as well? i need to build many such regex.

Comment: You need to generate the pattern for each range. Just remove the `\b` *word boundaries*. Additionally I changed the `(` *capture group* to a `(:` *non capture group*. Also you can add start `^` and `$` end *anchors*. [Regex101 is good tool for testing](https://regex101.com/r/aZ7gS7/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match numbers above `120` you can use

```
/\b10\.100\.1\.(?:12[1-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b/
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2pW0/3)

Comment: The values for that section of the IP address will only go up to 255.

Comment: So, doesn't it match them? Up to 255? See comment: *anything above 120 should be matched*. See the answer below: `[2-9][0-9][0-9]` will match `999`.

Comment: It does, but for an IP address, anything above 120 will mean 121-255 only. Anything outside that range should not be matched.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
10\.100\.1\.(12[1-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split it, and check the integer at the end?

```
def ips = ['10.100.1.121',
           '10.10.0.1',
           '10.100.1.119',
           '10.100.1.122']

def lastOctetGreaterThan(String ip, int number) {
    Integer.valueOf(ip.split(/\./).last()) > number
}

ips.each { ip ->
    println "$ip => ${lastOctetGreaterThan(ip, 120)}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
import java.net.InetAddress

def octet = InetAddress.getByName(ip)         // x.x.x.x -> InetAddress
                       .getAddress()          // InetAddress -> byte[]
                       .collect { it & 0xff } // positive numbers only
```

`octet[3]` is what you want. The code will work with IPv6 too.